# ERROR: not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this problem with this code:

```
class TTTEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging

    def recognize_input(self):
        self.logger.info("Waiting for user input.")
        text_transcript = input('>> ').lower()
        while text_transcript == '':
            self.logger.info("User didn't said something")
            text_transcript = input('>> ').lower()
        return text_transcript
```

I get this error with module 'logging' when i type a word in console input:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Comment: show the full stacktrace

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @AndresHernandez the full error message that you get in the console. It will begin with "Traceback (most recent call last)"

Comment: The problem is that I am getting this error through python's 'logging' module.

Comment: Do you have some try/except block somewhere that is catching and logging errors?

Comment: My log file show this:

2020-04-04 05:52:37,276 - root - ERROR - Speech and console error message: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int' - [tts.py:87]

Answer (score 0):

I think than the try/except that is logging errors is this:

```
try:
            while not self.message_queue.empty():

                cumulative_batch = ''
                message = self.message_queue.get()
                batches = self._create_text_batches(raw_text=message)

                for batch in batches:
                    self.tts_engine.say(batch)
                    cumulative_batch += batch
                    self.console_manager.console_output(cumulative_batch)
                    self.run_engine()
                    if self.stop_speaking:
                        self.logger.debug('Speech interruption triggered')
                        self.stop_speaking = False
                        break

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("Speech and console error message: {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Remove the try/except and what traceback do you get?

Comment: The log not show the error now. But i don't understand why '<' if i'm not sending that character.

Comment: The error is probably not in the code you have shared in your question

Answer (score 0):

This is tts.py complete file:

```
import threading
import logging
import pyttsx3
import queue


class TTS:
    """
    Text To Speech Engine (TTS)
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.tts_engine = self._set_voice_engine()

    def run_engine(self):
        try:
            self.tts_engine.runAndWait()
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def _set_voice_engine():
        """
        Setup text to speech engine
        :return: gtts engine object
        """
        tts_engine = pyttsx3.init()
        tts_engine.setProperty('rate', 160)  # Setting up new voice rate
        tts_engine.setProperty('volume', 1.0)  # Setting up volume level  between 0 and 1
        return tts_engine


class TTSEngine(TTS):
    def __init__(self, console_manager, speech_response_enabled):
        super().__init__()
        self.logger = logging
        self.message_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=5)  # Maxsize is the size of the queue / capacity of messages
        self.console_manager = console_manager
        self.speech_response_enabled = speech_response_enabled
        self.stop_speaking = False

    def assistant_response(self, message):
        """
        Assistant response in voice or/and in text.
        :param message: string
        """
        if self.speech_response_enabled:
            self._insert_into_message_queue(message)
            try:
                speech_tread = threading.Thread(target=self._speech_and_console)
                speech_tread.start()
            except RuntimeError as e:
                self.logger.error('Error in assistant response thread with message {0}'.format(e))

    def _insert_into_message_queue(self, message):
        try:
            if message:
                self.message_queue.put(message)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("Unable to insert message to queue with error message: {0}".format(e))

    def _speech_and_console(self):
        """
        Speech method translate text batches to speech and print them in the console.
        :param text: string (e.g 'tell me about google')
        """

        try:
            while not self.message_queue.empty():

                cumulative_batch = ''
                message = self.message_queue.get()
                batches = self._create_text_batches(raw_text=message)

                for batch in batches:
                    self.tts_engine.say(batch)
                    cumulative_batch += batch
                    self.console_manager.console_output(cumulative_batch)
                    self.run_engine()
                    if self.stop_speaking:
                        self.logger.debug('Speech interruption triggered')
                        self.stop_speaking = False
                        break

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("Speech and console error message: {0}".format(e))

    @staticmethod
    def _create_text_batches(raw_text, number_of_words_per_batch=8):
        """
        Splits the user speech message into batches and return a list with the split batches
        :param raw_text: string
        :param number_of_words_per_batch: int
        :return: list
        """
        raw_text = raw_text + ' '
        list_of_batches = []
        total_words = raw_text.count(' ')
        letter_id = 0

        for split in range(0, int(total_words / number_of_words_per_batch)):
            batch = ''
            words_count = 0
            while words_count < number_of_words_per_batch:
                batch += raw_text[letter_id]
                if raw_text[letter_id] == ' ':
                    words_count += 1
                letter_id += 1
            list_of_batches.append(batch)

        if letter_id < len(raw_text):  # Add the rest of word in a batch
            list_of_batches.append(raw_text[letter_id:])
        return list_of_batches
```